# python+selenium+Phantomjs+Unicodeerror: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, selenium, unicode, utf-8, phantomjs

few days ago, I could run the code successfully. But, today, when I use selenium + Phantomjs, there is an Unicoderroe occur.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
#Unicodeerror occur
driver.get(url)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\Desktop\test.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py", line 58, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 185, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 247, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 464, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 537, in _request
    body = data.decode('utf-8').replace('\x00', '').strip()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 189: invalid start byte
```

UnicodeDecodeError occcur in  Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py

I don't know how to fix it, please help me

Comment: Try this: after driver = webdriver.PhantomJS() add driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)

Comment: @giaco Error still occur. The error occur when the program execute "driver=webdriver.PhantomJS()". Program was stopped before executing  "driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)"

Comment: Huh I remember having similar issues without proper error message and one of them was solved with set_window. Did you try to remove selenium and install it again? What I know for shure is that Selenium and PhantomJS are both very buggy.

Comment: Do you maybe have any non asci character in path to selenium or python interpreter?

Comment: @giaco I have tried reinstall. But it's still wrong. I 'm confused that why I could run the program smoothly few days age.
Thanks for your help. I'll keep on figuring out the problem.

Comment: @giaco "C:\Users\name\Desktop\test.py" & "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium". I think the path is not the problem

Comment: The same thing happend to me(it worked until one day with that unicode error) and it was path problem. I use ubuntu since then :)

Comment: @giaco I agree. It can execute perfectly on Ubuntu. Why windows cant? it's a little weird. Thank you.

Comment: Because it's windows. You're welcome.

Comment: @giaco I agree .haha